# Can you compare enums in SQL with the LIKE operator

Tags: sql

Can you compare two enums in SQL with the LIKE operator?

Comment: Second part agree, thanks. First part: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html

Comment: If you are asking about MySQL, you should add the <mysql> tag to your question. That product does things in its own way, sometimes.

Comment: I would like to know how to find out which SQL version is used in my project, when all I have is backend code (Java sprint boot, H2). How can I tell? Is there any cues in this specific (SB+H2) situation? Any commands to run in this specific (SB+H2) situation?

Comment: At https://dbfiddle.uk/ you can find different ways to find out dbms and its version. Unfortunately there's no general answer.